# AL8116 datasheet error?

Tags: led

I am trying to understand Typical Application Circuit from AL8116 datasheet and I am struggling to make any sense of it. For example, what is the point of having transformer connected though diode to GND and Vcc if those pins will always be at the same potential? Am I missing something or it is an obvious mistake?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diode isn't directly connected to VCC and GND; there is a diode and capacitor that form a half-wave rectifier. Presumably, the transformer has some primary winding connected to an AC supply (possibly mains or the flyback transformer of the AL1665/AL1666 if configured that way) which is not clearly shown in this image.

As long as the capacitance is sufficient to hold up the voltage and avoid triggering the undervoltage-lockout in each AC cycle, the chip will be powered from that rectifier.

Comment: Thanks for answer. If they would show primary winding it would be easier to understand.